# Dynamic array to JSON or Table to JSON

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I've searched and attempted to get this working for a few weeks and I'm still failing. I've tried several ways including reg expressions. I have a dynamic table that I scrape with puppeteer and I'm trying to output that data as JSON. The problem is that the header "2nd flr (Rm 226)" & 'Location - Room 115' May or may not show. The events in these rooms may have 1 or multiple events. How do I convert dynamic data like this and ensure that I get everything listed?

I'm trying to get something like this JSON.

```
data: [

  {
    "location": "2nd flr (Rm 226)"
    "time": "10:00 AM",
    "description": "Social Security Administration Commissioner",
    "document": "18",
    "type": "Social Security Hearing",
    "blank": " ",
    "order": "Hearing"
  },
  {
    "location": "2nd flr (Rm 226)"
    "time": "01:00 PM",
    "description:"
    "Social Security Administration Commissioner",
    "document": "18",
    "type": "Order Setting Social Security Hearing",
    "blank": " ",
    order: "Hearing"

  },
  {
    "location": "3rd flr (100)"
    "time": "01:00 PM",
    "description:"
    "Social Security Administration Commissioner",
    "document": "18",
    "type": "Order Setting Social Security Hearing",
    "blank": " ",
    order: "Hearing"

  }

]


const data = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('#content > table > tbody > tr'),
  row => Array.from(row.querySelectorAll('td'), cell => cell.innerText)
)
```

Here is the output that I get.

```
{
  "data": [
    [
      "2nd flr (Rm 226)"
    ],
    [
      "10:00 AM",
      "Social Security Administration Commissioner",
      "18",
      "Social Security Hearing",
      " ",
      "Hearing"
    ],
    [
      "01:00 PM",
      "Social Security Administration Commissioner",
      "18",
      "Order Setting Social Security Hearing",
      " ",
      "Hearing"
    ],
    [
      "3rd flr (100)"
    ],
    [
      "09:30 AM",
      "TERMINATED on 03/23/2015",
      "34",
      "Resetting Hearings",
      " ",
      "Hearing"
    ],
    [
      " ",
      "Reserved for case",
      "23",
      "Motion Hearing",
      " ",
      "Hearing"
    ],
    [
      "01:00 PM",
      "Case Information",
      "19",
      "Order Setting",
      " ",
      "Hearing"
    ],
    [
      "01:30 PM",
      "Case information",
      "31",
      "Order Setting",
      " ",
      "Hearing"
    ],
    [
      " ",
      "TERMINATED on 06/14/2019",
      "16",
      "Order Setting/Resetting Hearings",
      " ",
      "Hearing"
    ],
    [
      "3rd flr (Rm 310)"
    ],
    [
      "01:30 PM",
      "Insurance Company",
      "122",
      "Order Setting/Resetting Hearings",
      " ",
      "Hearing"
    ]
  ]
}
```

```
<center><Table border=1 width=98%>
<TR><TD id='report' class='report' align=center><B><FONT SIZE=+2>Daily Calendar Report of 09/23/2019</font></B><BR><CENTER></table></center>
<Table border=1 width=98%   >

<TR><TD class='room' id='room' ALIGN=CENTER COLSPAN=6><STRONG>2nd flr (Rm 226)</STRONG></TD></TR>
<TR id='casedata' class='casedata'>
<TD class=case-0 id=case-0 VALIGN=top NOWRAP>10:00 AM</TD>
<TD class=case-1 id=case-1 VALIGN=top><A HREF=/Reportpt.pl?55244>Social Security Administration</A><B></B></TD>
<TD class=case-2 id=case-2 VALIGN=top>18</TD>
<TD class=case-3 id=case-3 VALIGN=top>Security Hearing</TD>
<TD class=case-4 id=case-4 VALIGN=top>&nbsp</TD>
<TD class=case-5 id=case-5 VALIGN=top NOWRAP><I>Hearing</I></TD>
</TR>

<TR><TD class='room' id='room' ALIGN=CENTER COLSPAN=6><STRONG>2nd flr (Rm 406)</STRONG></TD></TR>
<TR id='casedata' class='casedata'>
<TD class=case-0 id=case-0 VALIGN=top NOWRAP>1:30 PM</TD>
<TD class=case-1 id=case-1 VALIGN=top><A HREF=/Reportpt.pl?55244>Social Security Administration</A><B></B></TD>
<TD class=case-2 id=case-2 VALIGN=top>18</TD>
<TD class=case-3 id=case-3 VALIGN=top>Security Hearing</TD>
<TD class=case-4 id=case-4 VALIGN=top>&nbsp</TD>
<TD class=case-5 id=case-5 VALIGN=top NOWRAP><I>Hearing</I></TD>
</TR>
</table>
```

```
const tds = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#Content > table > tbody > tr > td'));
const trs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#Content > table > tbody > tr'))

const data = Array.from(
      document.querySelectorAll('#Content > table > tbody > tr'),
      row => Array.from(row.querySelectorAll('td'), cell => cell.innerText),
      data =>{ return ( [data] ) }
    )
```

Comment: It looks like `innertText` doesn't always get you what you want. It would be helpful if you could provide the HTML you are trying to scrape from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look for further clues in your HTML to achieve the structure you desire. In this case I looked for the class of the first `td` in each `tr`.

[[ I know you are only *reading* the HTML, but it is **faulty**, as there are multiple identical `id`s assigned (`room`) in it ...]]

```js
// define shortcut function qsa: querySelectorAll, returning a proper array
// An HTML context `el` can be given as an optional second parameter
function qsa(s,el){
 return Array.prototype.map.call((el?Element:Document).prototype
             .querySelectorAll.call((el||document),s),function(e){return e})
}
data=[];
qsa('tr').forEach(function(tr,i,arr){
 var tds=qsa('td',tr); 
 if (tds[0].className=='room') 
  arr.room=tds[0].innerText // "remember" the current room data ...
 else if (tds[0].className=='case-0') 
  data.push([arr.room].concat(tds.map(function(e){return e.innerText}))) // output room and row data
});

console.log(data)

// and, of course, the JSON is created by
var JSONdata=JSON.stringify(data);
```

```html
<center><Table border=1 width=98%>
<TR><TD id='report' class='report' align=center><B><FONT SIZE=+2>Daily Calendar Report of 09/23/2019</font></B><BR><CENTER></table></center>
<Table border=1 width=98%   >

<TR><TD class='room' id='room' ALIGN=CENTER COLSPAN=6><STRONG>2nd flr (Rm 226)</STRONG></TD></TR>
<TR id='casedata' class='casedata'>
<TD class=case-0 id=case-0 VALIGN=top NOWRAP>10:00 AM</TD>
<TD class=case-1 id=case-1 VALIGN=top><A HREF=/Reportpt.pl?55244>Social Security Administration</A><B></B></TD>
<TD class=case-2 id=case-2 VALIGN=top>18</TD>
<TD class=case-3 id=case-3 VALIGN=top>Security Hearing</TD>
<TD class=case-4 id=case-4 VALIGN=top>&nbsp</TD>
<TD class=case-5 id=case-5 VALIGN=top NOWRAP><I>Hearing</I></TD>
</TR>

<TR><TD class='room' id='room' ALIGN=CENTER COLSPAN=6><STRONG>2nd flr (Rm 406)</STRONG></TD></TR>
<TR id='casedata' class='casedata'>
<TD class=case-0 id=case-0 VALIGN=top NOWRAP>1:30 PM</TD>
<TD class=case-1 id=case-1 VALIGN=top><A HREF=/Reportpt.pl?55244>Social Security Administration</A><B></B></TD>
<TD class=case-2 id=case-2 VALIGN=top>18</TD>
<TD class=case-3 id=case-3 VALIGN=top>Security Hearing</TD>
<TD class=case-4 id=case-4 VALIGN=top>&nbsp</TD>
<TD class=case-5 id=case-5 VALIGN=top NOWRAP><I>Hearing</I></TD>
</TR>
</table>
```

This solution might seem a bit old-fashioned (no `Array.from`, no arrow functions). I wrote it so it will still work in IE.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you have the right title. Getting json is easy, just use JSON.stringify Your problem is getting the objects you want to convert to be consistent, or at least the way you want them - it looks like the code is generating lots of arrays, rather than an array of objects

So I think you have to do more work parsing the html. I would console log the objects coming from the html to check it before converting to json.

So you could read each `<td>` explicitly, rather than in the loop, assigning either the value to the object or a default value

Comment: How can I read each TD explicitly if I don't know how many td there will be on any given day?

Comment: Did you consol log all the td and tr? This is your best debug clue. Your example shows consistent td in the html.